# Weird plot in python

Tags: python, python-3.6

just want to ask why this code is not working, i am reading a file with 4 columns and the idea is to plot the last 3 against the 1 one. but there is an incompatible thing that i do not get, do you have any idea how to fix it?

```
import numpy as np

import cmath as math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dataplanck1 = 'COM_PowerSpect_CMB-TT-full_R3.01.txt'
dataplanck2 = 'COM_PowerSpect_CMB-EE-full_R3.01.txt'
dataplanck3 = 'COM_PowerSpect_CMB-TE-full_R3.01.txt'
datawmap1 = 'wmap_tt_spectrum_9yr_v5.txt'
datawmap2 = 'wmap_ee_spectrum_9yr_v5.txt'
datawmap3 = 'wmap_te_spectrum_9yr_v5.txt'

multipole = []
dls = []
dlse1 = []
dlse2 = []

with open(dataplanck1) as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        row = line.split()
        multipole.append(row[0])
        dls.append(row[1])
        dlse1.append(row[2])
        dlse2.append(row[3])


plt.plot(multipole, dls, label='Synthetic masked ')
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

That makes no sense. also the data has this format:

```
 2.00000000e+00   2.25895000e+02   1.32369000e+02   5.33062000e+02
  3.00000000e+00   9.36920000e+02   4.50471000e+02   1.21230800e+03
  4.00000000e+00   6.92238000e+02   2.94111000e+02   6.66469000e+02
  5.00000000e+00   1.50170500e+03   5.74432000e+02   1.15580400e+03
  6.00000000e+00   5.57611000e+02   2.01242000e+02   3.75763000e+02
  7.00000000e+00   1.15264300e+03   3.81584000e+02   6.70824000e+02
  8.00000000e+00   6.15846000e+02   1.91997000e+02   3.23446000e+02
  9.00000000e+00   6.97821000e+02   2.14638000e+02   3.49581000e+02
  1.00000000e+01   8.03658000e+02   2.32846000e+02   3.67945000e+02
  1.10000000e+01   8.69580000e+02   2.40260000e+02   3.71043000e+02
  1.20000000e+01   7.64074000e+02   2.04951000e+02   3.10576000e+02
  1.30000000e+01   5.99003000e+02   1.58593000e+02   2.35581000e+02
```

Comment: You are using input files that people looking at the problem don't have access to, and it is a lot to ask people to consider the full intent of your code. Would recommend revising the code to show the first unexpected behavior for you, and posting that - not necessarily the entire set of logic. There should be enough info available in the question for it to be self-contained, e.g. not links to other input files.

Comment: Looks like you're reading the numbers as strings and not converting them to floats? Try changing the `row = line.split()` line to `row = [float(n) for n in line.split()]`.